# Probability bound of the difference of order statistics for correlated and identical Gaussian random variables

Tags: extreme-value, order-statistics, dependent-variable

Suppose, there are $n$ identical and correlated Gaussian random variables namely, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ with $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $i\in\{1,2, ...n\}$. The correlation coefficient between any two of them is upper bounded by a value $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, i.e., $\rho_{i,j}\le\varepsilon, \forall i\ne j; i,j\in[n]$. Then the order statistics of them can be denoted as $X_{(1)}\le X_{(2)} \le ...\le X_{(n)}$.

In this case, is it possible to calculate the upper bound of $Pr[X_{(k)}-X_{(l)}\le \tau]$ (or, is there any research paper exists which calculated such bound for correlated and identical Gaussian random variables) where, $X_{(k)}$ and $X_{(l)}$ are $k$-th and $l$-th order statistic with $l<k$. Even the bound for extreme case (i.e., $Pr[X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}\le\tau]$) would be helpful.

Comment: In the two-variable case, where $X$ and $Y$ are binormally distributed with variances $\sigma^2$ and correlation $\rho$, we have \begin{align}X-Y&\sim N(0,(2-2\rho)\sigma^2)\\Pr\big[\tau\ge|X-Y|\big]&=2\Phi\!\left(\frac{\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{2-2\rho}}\right)-1\end{align} But even for three variables I don't see any exact formula.

Comment: Yes, I know this bound for $n=2$. In fact, I can calculate a trivial bound for $n\ge 2$ (using union bound over all possible pairs). But, I'm looking for a tighter bound. Anyway, thank you for your insight. @MattF.